# Green's function for 1D Klein Gordon equation in position space

Tags: partial-differential-equations, greens-function

I want to derive the Green's function for the 1D Klein Gordon equation in position space. The Klein-Gordon equation in 1D:
\begin{equation}
(\partial_t^2-\partial_z^2+m^2)\phi=f(z,t)
\end{equation}
where $f$ is an arbitrary source.
The Green's function is defined as 
\begin{equation}
(\partial_t^2-\partial_z^2+m^2)G(z,t)=\delta(z)\delta(t)
\end{equation}
In Fourier space I get:
\begin{equation}
\hat{G}(k,\omega)=\frac{1}{(-\omega^2+k^2+m^2)}=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{k^2+m^2}}\Big(\frac{1}{\omega-\sqrt{k^2+m^2}}-\frac{1}{\omega+\sqrt{k^2+m^2}}\Big).
\end{equation}
The Back transformation is
\begin{equation}
G(z,t)=-\int\frac{dz}{2\pi}e^{ikz}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{k^2+m^2}}\int\frac{d\omega}{2\pi}e^{-i\omega t}\Big(\frac{1}{\omega-\sqrt{k^2+m^2}}-\frac{1}{\omega+\sqrt{k^2+m^2}}\Big)
\end{equation}
To evaluate the $\omega$ integral I have to shift the poles. Here I want to calculate the \textbf{retarded} Greens function and therefore I shift both poles into the lower half plane (see figure).

[image: Integration contour]
I therefore have to evaluate integrals of the form
\begin{equation}
F(t):=\int\frac{d\omega}{2\pi}e^{-i\omega t}\frac{1}{\omega-\omega_0+i\epsilon},~~~\omega_0\in\mathbb{R}
\end{equation}
The integral over the circle in the lower half plane can be parameterized by $\omega=Re^{i\phi}$ with $\phi\in (\pi,2\pi)$. We therefore have for $t>0:$ that $|e^{-i\omega t}|=|e^{-iRe^{i\phi}t}|=|e^{R\sin\phi t}|\overset{R\rightarrow\infty}{\rightarrow}0$. Therefore in the limit $R\rightarrow\infty$ we have
\begin{equation}
F(t)=\oint t\frac{d\omega}{2\pi}e^{-i\omega t}\frac{1}{\omega-\omega_0+i\epsilon}=-i\text{Res}\big[\frac{e^{-i\omega t}}{\omega-\omega_0+i\epsilon}\big]_{|\omega=\omega_0-i\epsilon}=-ie^{-i\omega_0 t} e^{-\epsilon t}\overset{\epsilon\rightarrow0}{\rightarrow}-ie^{-i\omega_0 t}
\end{equation}
where the minus is coming from running in the mathematical negative direction. Therefore the retarded Green's function is:
\begin{equation}
G(z,t)=i\Theta(t)\int\frac{dk}{2\pi}e^{ikz}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{k^2+m^2}}\Big(e^{-i\sqrt{k^2+m^2} t}-e^{i\sqrt{k^2+m^2} t}\Big)
\end{equation}
where I have also introduced the $\Theta(t)$, since the integrals which I have evalueted with the residue theorem only converge if $t>0$.

The question is now how I can evaluate the $k$ integral? If I look up the endresult inn wikipedia it should be
\begin{equation}
G(z,t)=\frac{1}{2}\big(1-\sin(m t)\big)\big(\delta(t-z)-\delta(t+z)\big)+\frac{m}{2}\Theta(t-|z|)J_0(um), ~~~u=\sqrt{t^2-z^2}
\end{equation}
I guess since I calculate the retarded solution, that I cannot get the term $\delta(t+z)$? Also I do not have a clue how to evaluate the integral to end up with the result from wikipedia? I have tried several things: Partial integration, substituting a $\text{sinh}$ to get rid off the square roots. Nothing has worked so far, so if you have a good idea this would be great!

Many thanks!

Comment: $k=m \sinh u$ seems like a good substitution. It will definitely get your last integral in a Bessel form

Comment: After the substitution I get $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}due^{im\sinh(u)z}\big(e^{-im\cosh(u)t}-e^{im\cosh(u)t}\big)$. I still don't see how I can get a Bessel funktion here? I could deform the integration path to run along the imaginary axis, but then I would get factors with sin and cos in the exponentials?

Comment: That's what Bessel functions are. I'm not sure how to get the particular form from your answer, but any integral with trigonometric or hyperbolic functions in the exponent is related to Bessel functions